# Aws Cognito: How to authorize a user in a serverless stack using custom attributes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, lambda-authorizer

**Problem:**
In my app users are part of a team and can access the teams resources (such as tasks). When a user is making a get request for a task I have to verify that that user is part of the team that owns the task. How would I go about to do that in my stack?

**Stack:**
I have a Api Gateway in form of a HttpApi with a bunch of Lambdas behind it that gets the resources from a DynamoDb table.

**Current Solution:**
I have configured a JWT authorizer on the routes and are sending the access token that my users get when they log in to the lambdas. This containes the user ID. I use this id to make an extra call to the db to check which teams it has access to. This means an extra call to the dynamo db per request.

**What would a better solution look like?**
I am used to adding claims to my tokens that are needed to authorize resources (I have been running many identity servers at different companies) but this does not seem to be how it is done in this stack. I am not sure what the "recommended" way of authorizing a user with information other than the user Id with a aws serverless stack. Please advice =)

**Here is the project source** (work in progress etc):
https://github.com/stilren/typescript-cdk-react/tree/master/backend

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using "CognitoIdentityServiceProvider" to get the user using the access token - Im guessing that is the intended solution. This means a call to the idp instead of dynamodb extra so still not being what I was looking for really but I guess I could cache the response (maybe even in the gateway?)

Here is the code to get the user using auth token
https://github.com/stilren/typescript-cdk-react/commit/72821b0df1373a556c30d5362da5f7cab30a5bd8#diff-3d5ea31f509f495ef777ea9120e4b996

This is the full commit to grant access to update user attributes from a lambda using cdk:
https://github.com/stilren/typescript-cdk-react/commit/72821b0df1373a556c30d5362da5f7cab30a5bd8